# Permutations to compare two different string to match

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I'm cracking my head here to solve this problem.

I'm trying to compare two strings like:

```
a = 'apple'
b = 'ppale'
```

If I user permutation method, variable `b` could be re-generated and it can match with the variable `a`.

I wrote the code, god knows why, I'm only getting `False` value even when I'm expecting `True`.

```
import itertools

def gen(char, phrase):
    char = list(char)

    wordsList = list(map(''.join, itertools.permutations(char)))
    for word in wordsList:
        if word == phrase:
            return True
        else:
            return False

print(gen('apple', 'appel')) # should be True
print(gen('apple', 'elppa')) # should be True
print(gen('apple', 'ap')) # should be False
```

Comment: When you `return` inside a `for` loop, no further loop iterations occur — which in this case means that only the first word permutation is checked and at that point either `True` or `False` from the comparison will be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're returning on the first iteration of the loop, regardless of whether there's a match or not.  In particular, you're returning `False` the *first* time there's a mismatch.  Instead, you need to complete the entire loop before returning `False`:

```
def gen(char, phrase):
    char = list(char)

    wordsList = list(map(''.join, itertools.permutations(char)))
    for word in wordsList:
        if word == phrase:
            return True
    return False
```

Note that there are some improvements that can be made.  One is there's no need to do `char = list(char)`, since `char` is already an iterable.  Also, there's no need to expand the map result into a list.  It's just being used as an iterable, so it can be used directly, which can potentially save a lot of memory:

```
def gen(char, phrase):
    wordsIter = map(''.join, itertools.permutations(char))
    for word in wordsIter:
        if word == phrase:
            return True
    return False
```

However, since you're just comparing two words for the same characters, you don't really need to generate *all* the permutations.  Instead, you just need to check to see of the two sets of characters are the same (allowing for multiple instances of characters, so technically you want to compare two *multisets*).  You can do this *much* more efficiently as follows:

```
import collections

def gen(char, phrase):
    counter1 = collections.Counter(char)
    counter2 = collections.Counter(phrase)
    return counter1 == counter2
```

This is an O(n) algorithm, which is the best that can be done for this problem.  This is *much* faster than generating the permutations.  For long strings, it's also significantly faster than sorting the letters and comparing the sorted results, which is O(n*log(n)).

Example output:

```
>>> gen("apple", "elxpa")
False
>>> gen("apple", "elppa")
True
>>> gen("apple", "elpa")
False
>>>
```

Note that this only returns `True` if the letters are the same, and the number of each letter is the same.

If you want to speed up the case where the two strings have different lengths, you could add a fast check up front that returns `False` if the lengths differ, before counting the characters.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason it's not working is this that your loop is returning `False` back to the caller as soon as the first non-match occurs. What you want is something like this:

```
for word in wordsList:
    if word == phrase:
        return True
return False
```

which will test one or more permutations; if one matches, it will return `True` immediately, but only after they all fail to match will it return `False`.

Also, there's no need to do the `char = list(char)`. A string is an iterable, just like a `list`, so you can use it as an argument to `permutations()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this much more simply: sort the letter in each word and compare for equality.

```
def gen(a, b):
    return sorted(a) == sorted(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate method you can use is to just loop through the letters of one word, and remove the letters in the other word if it exists. If after the iteration of the first word, the second word is empty, it is an anagram:

```
def anagram(word1, word2):
  for letter in word1:
    word2 = word2.replace(letter,"",1)
  if word2 == "":
    return True
  return False

a = "apple"
b = "pleap"

print(anagram(a,b)) #returns True

a = "apple"
b = "plaap"

print(anagram(a,b)) #returns False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def string_permute(first_str: str, second_str: str) -> bool:
    cache = {}
    for ch in first_str:
        cache[ch] = cache.get(ch, 0) + 1
    for ch in second_str:
        cache[ch] = cache.get(ch, 0) - 1
    for ch in cache:
        if cache[ch] != 0:
            return False
    return True
```

O(n) time and O(n) Space complexity